# UISegmentedControl with UICollectionView Error with Switch Statement

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have **two arrays** of data that I am trying to switch between using a `UISegmentedControl`, then the data is to be displayed in a `UICollectionView`. So in the storyboard I have 2 segments for the Segment Control to match the two arrays. Currently the data is not displaying and the following switch statements falls to the default `prinln`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

var number: Int = 0

switch tabs.selectedSegmentIndex {

case 0: number = array1.count

case 1: number = array2.count

default: println("error counting array for number of items in section")

}

return number
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas where I may be going wrong ? This is the first time I have tried using a segmented control.

**Here is my View Controller code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabs: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var array1 = [Type1]()
var array2 = [Type2]()

func loadData() {

    var error: NSError?

    let request1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Type1")
    request1.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    self.array1 = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request1, error: &error) as! [Type1]

    let request2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Type2")
    request2.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    self.array2 = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: &error) as! [Type2]

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section

    var number: Int = 0

    switch tabs.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0: number = array1.count

    case 1: number = array2.count

    default: println("error counting array for number of items in section")

    }

    return number
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell

    var data1 = array1[indexPath.row]
    var data2 = array2[indexPath.row]

    switch tabs.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.data1[indexPath.row].title

    case 1:

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.data2[indexPath.row].title

    default: println("error with switch statement for cell data")

    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


}
```

Comment: please add the full error message, and which line throws the error, you can use `Breakpoints` to debug

Comment: @Aladin check my edits, thanks

Comment: Add the current value of `selectedSegmentedIndex` to the error message, you will see why it is hitting `default`: `println("tabs.selectedSegmentedIndex = \(tabs.selectedSegmentedIndex)")`

Comment: From the documentation:
 
>The default value is UISegmentedControlNoSegment (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.

Comment: print your segment index and see what value it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` set `selectedSegmentedIndex` to 0 (or 1) because the default value is -1.

```
tabs.selectedSegmentedIndex = 0
```

> The default value is UISegmentedControlNoSegment (no segment selected) until the user touches a segment. Set this property to -1 to turn off the current selection.

Comment: Yes that fixed the error ! Thanks but It is not however displaying the data :/

Comment: You need to reload your collection view after changing the selected segmented. Try `collectionView.reloadData()`.

Comment: So I need to create a `IBAction` for the segmented control to reload the data. But when loading the view it populates the array and reloads the data with the `loadData` function, and sets the `selectedSegmentedControl` to 0 but it doesn't display the data from the switch statements for the case 0. PS: It doesn't actually display neither data. Should I repost as a separate question :/

Comment: I would post a new question because it is different problem. A new title could call more attention to what is really the current problem. Also mark this answer as the right one if it solves your problem.

Comment: Alright so there must have been two problems going on, the one you have answered. Then the one for the original question I asked about the Array Index. The problem was with my switch statement when configuring the cell, I had to call each var data1 = array1[indexPath.row] in the correct case of the switch statement and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

nothing works for me but try this.
just call this line of code in the viewDidLoad method when you add  UISegmentedControl programmatically
UISegmentedControl action name then add your segmentedTabar var name or IBOutlet name like this:

```
segmentedTabarButtonsTap(segmentedTabbar)
```

segmentedTabarButtonsTap is segmentedTabbar action and
segmentedTabbar is segmentedTabbar var name